# Get Redis Status Through Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line, redis

I would like to retrieve the Redis status using a Ruby script, I tried the following commands:

```
redis_status_command, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3(`redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 info|grep status`)
```

OR

```
redis_status_command, stdeerr, status = Open3.capture3(`systemctl status redis`)
```

Then when I try to print the variable `redis_status_command` it returns a blank space, but I know that the commands that are inside the `Open3.capture3` part work in the command line. How can I retrieve the Redis status using Ruby? Thank you

Comment: Does the redis-rb gem contain what you are looking for? - https://github.com/redis/redis-rb

Answer (score 4):

With the "redis" gem, you can get all the info properties as follows:

```
require 'redis'
client = Redis.new(
  url: "redis://your-host.your-domain.com",
  port: 6379
)
client.info
```

The output will be a Hash of the info:

```
{
  "redis_version" => "3.2.4",
  "redis_git_sha1" => "0",
  "redis_git_dirty" => "0",
  "redis_build_id" => "0",
  "redis_mode" => "standalone",
  "os" => "Amazon ElastiCache",
  "arch_bits" => "64",
  "multiplexing_api" => "epoll",
  "gcc_version" => "0.0.0",
  "process_id" => "1",
  "run_id" => "73f5f76133b7bfd66eb89850a2f9df43e838f567",
  "tcp_port" => "6379",
  "uptime_in_seconds" => "1754115",
  "uptime_in_days" => "20",
  "hz" => "10",
  "lru_clock" => "5884700",
  "executable" => "-",
  "config_file" => "-",
  "connected_clients" => "10",
  "client_longest_output_list" => "0",
  "client_biggest_input_buf" => "0",
  "blocked_clients" => "0",
  "used_memory" => "16110168",
  "used_memory_human" => "15.36M",
  "used_memory_rss" => "19808256",
  "used_memory_rss_human" => "18.89M",
  "used_memory_peak" => "19915496",
  "used_memory_peak_human" => "18.99M",
  "used_memory_lua" => "37888",
  "used_memory_lua_human" => "37.00K",
  "maxmemory" => "6501171200",
  "maxmemory_human" => "6.05G",
  "maxmemory_policy" => "volatile-lru",
  "mem_fragmentation_ratio" => "1.23",
  "mem_allocator" => "jemalloc-4.0.3",
  "loading" => "0",
  "rdb_changes_since_last_save" => "30264",
  "rdb_bgsave_in_progress" => "0",
  "rdb_last_save_time" => "1497302809",
  "rdb_last_bgsave_status" => "ok",
  "rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec" => "-1",
  "rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec" => "-1",
  "aof_enabled" => "0",
  "aof_rewrite_in_progress" => "0",
  "aof_rewrite_scheduled" => "0",
  "aof_last_rewrite_time_sec" => "-1",
  "aof_current_rewrite_time_sec" => "-1",
  "aof_last_bgrewrite_status" => "ok",
  "aof_last_write_status" => "ok",
  "total_connections_received" => "29746",
  "total_commands_processed" => "3809776",
  "instantaneous_ops_per_sec" => "1",
  "total_net_input_bytes" => "382270539",
  "total_net_output_bytes" => "3134102675",
  "instantaneous_input_kbps" => "0.05",
  "instantaneous_output_kbps" => "0.03",
  "rejected_connections" => "0",
  "sync_full" => "1",
  "sync_partial_ok" => "0",
  "sync_partial_err" => "0",
  "expired_keys" => "0",
  "evicted_keys" => "0",
  "keyspace_hits" => "674",
  "keyspace_misses" => "318",
  "pubsub_channels" => "0",
  "pubsub_patterns" => "0",
  "latest_fork_usec" => "162",
  "migrate_cached_sockets" => "0",
  "role" => "master",
  "connected_slaves" => "1",
  "slave0" => "ip=192.168.1.2,port=6379,state=online,offset=341359205,lag=0",
  "master_repl_offset" => "341359205",
  "repl_backlog_active" => "1",
  "repl_backlog_size" => "1048576",
  "repl_backlog_first_byte_offset" => "340310630",
  "repl_backlog_histlen" => "1048576",
  "used_cpu_sys" => "494.00",
  "used_cpu_user" => "912.16",
  "used_cpu_sys_children" => "0.00",
  "used_cpu_user_children" => "0.00",
  "cluster_enabled" => "0",
  "db0" => "keys=3479,expires=0,avg_ttl=0"
}
```